# Making LaTeX tabular environment behave 'well' under copy/paste

Tags: tables, copy-paste

Whenever I copy a table created with LaTeX's `tabular` environment from the output `.pdf` file and paste it into another application, all the entries go to different lines. Worse, the first column is copied, then the second, and so on.

Is there a way to make the table behave as expected by Joe User? That is, the 'flow' of the table as generated by LaTeX should be line-wise, not column-wise: If I select a line, the line should be subject to copy and paste.  Right now, however, selecting a line marks almost the whole table...

Here is some sample code; the image shows what happens if I try to select the line by clicking on the left side of 'd' and releasing the mouse right of 'f'.  The expected behaviour is that the line 'def' gets marked and nothing else.

Note that the current (unwanted) marking behaviour is rather universal for all PDF viewers; it is thus really an issue with TeX.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{rrr}
a & b & c\\
d & e & f\\
g & h & i
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: marking the middle line]

I'm quite sure this is a deep issue, since the building of tables vertically is probably at the very heart of the TeX engine.

Comment: Why not copy and paste from the `.tex` file instead of the `.pdf`?

Comment: This is for my CV, and employers will have the .pdf file. If they copy text directly, I want to make sure formatting is preserved

Comment: Could you show us what your `tabular` code looks like that is causing an incorrect copy-and-paste? It depends on how you typeset it, but it is possible to select the contents first by row or first by column.

Comment: Isn't that an issue of your PDF viewer or your word processor? I am just asking because of features like on the following page: http://nightcrawlerinshadow.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/advanced-text-selection-in-okular/

Comment: it works just fine on my system...