# Avoid Underfull \vbox and \hbox in longtable?

Tags: longtable

I want to use longtable (because the table contains more than one page), but I got so many error:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 2005) in paragraph at lines 22--23
\TU/lmr/m/n/10 menampilkan nilai \TU/lmr/m/it/10 vari-

Overfull \hbox (56.43303pt too wide) in alignment at lines 8--27
 [] [] [] [] []
```

I have made my table smaller but nothing works. I also tried to add `@{}` but no luck. I tried [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275305/underfull-hbox-badness-10000-in-longtable) solution. The black overfull bar is gone, but the error still exists. Is this because latex need to force my table content to  breakline ? Is this OK to have all those warning ?

This is my MWE

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{longtable} % add table
\overfullrule=2cm % show overfull

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}[c]{|p{1cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{2cm}|p{1cm}|}
  \hline
  \textbf{No.\newline Jalur} & \textbf{Prosedur Uji} &
                                                    \textbf{\emph{Expected Result}}
  & \textbf{\emph{Result}} & \textbf{Status} \\\hline
  %
  1 & Menjalankan \emph{ssh\_out\_stream} dengan \emph{exit\_status\_ready()} bernilai
      \emph{true} & \emph{ssh\_out\_stream} akan berhenti berjalan & \emph{As expected} & Valid \\\hline
      %
  2 & Menjalankan \emph{ssh\_out\_stream} dengan \emph{variable} \emph{length} bernilai
      lebih kecil dari 0 & \emph{ssh\_out\_stream} tidak akan menampilkan nilai \emph{variable} \emph{length}
  & \emph{As expected} & Valid \\\hline
  %
  3 & Menjalankan \emph{ssh\_out\_stream} dengan \emph{variable} \emph{length} bernilai
      lebih besar dari 0 & \emph{ssh\_out\_stream} akan menampilkan nilai \emph{variable} \emph{length}
  & \emph{As expected} & Valid \\\hline
  %
  \caption{Pengujian \emph{unit} \emph{ssh\_out\_stream}}
  \label{jalur:ssh_out_stream}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- your table is much wider than text area,
- you can increase text width by use of the package `geometry` or define narrower second and third column (later is not recommended)
- width of the first and the last column is to small, better is used natural width of column (see mwe below)
- width of the second column is to small for nice fitting oc cell column into its cells
- with use of the `ragged2e` package you can better align text in cells.
- for column headers i suggest to use `\thead` macro from the `makecell` package
- more vertical space around cells contents you can obtain with the macro `\makegappedcells` also from the package `\makecell`

off-topic

- table caption, special at `longtable` should be on the top of table

  ```
  \documentclass{report}
  \usepackage{geometry}   % new

  \usepackage{ragged2e}
  \usepackage{longtable,
              makecell}   % new
  \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}}  % new
  \renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}    % new
  \setcellgapes{3pt}                          % new
  \overfullrule=2cm % show overfull

  %-------------------------------------- only for show page layout
  \usepackage{showframe}
  \renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.25pt}
  \renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
  %---------------------------------------------------------------%

  \begin{document}

  {\makegapedcells    % new
   \begin{longtable}{|c|L{5cm}|L{4cm}|>{\itshape}L{2cm}|c|}   % changed
  \caption{Pengujian \emph{unit} \emph{ssh\_out\_stream}}
      \label{jalur:ssh_out_stream}                \\
      \hline
  \thead{No.\\ Jalur}
      &   \thead{Prosedur\\ Uji}
              &   \itshape\thead{Expected\\ Result}
                  &   \thead{Result}
                      &   \thead{Status}          \\
      \hline
    %
  1   &   Menjalankan \emph{ssh\_out\_stream} dengan \emph{exit\_status\_ready()} bernilai \emph{true}
          &   \emph{ssh\_out\_stream} akan berhenti berjalan
              &   As expected         & Valid \\
      \hline
  2   & Menjalankan \emph{ssh\_out\_stream} dengan \emph{variable} \emph{length} bernilai lebih kecil dari 0
          &   \emph{ssh\_out\_stream} tidak akan menampilkan nilai \emph{variable} \emph{length}
              &   As expected         & Valid      \\
      \hline
  3   & Menjalankan \emph{ssh\_out\_stream} dengan \emph{variable} \emph{length} bernilai lebih besar dari 0
          &   \emph{ssh\_out\_stream} akan menampilkan nilai \emph{variable} \emph{length}
              &   As expected         & Valid      \\
  \end{longtable}
  }
  ```

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

Comment: I still get [this](https://paste.debian.net/1048454/) warning. Is it OK ?

Comment: see edit. no warnings, no bad boxes. anyway, warning are not errors and not harm of your table design ...

Comment: Wow, awesome thank you. Sorry, I want to ask. I *think* warning comes from long word that need to break in narrow column, then latex break that word for me with a warning. Is it okay to have document with many warning like this (just because long words) ?.  It doesn't do harm, But I am afraid this will contribute to other error like longtable overriding page number or etc ? are we have to take those warning seriously or just can we just leave it ?

Any way thanks lot for this solution

Comment: @azzamsa, you need load babel with your language in your document preamble. it will help to hyphenate long words. the package `ragged2e` enable this on the smart way. full or overfull  will not cause that `longtable` 
 will overriding text area.